# How can i apply something to each one of my columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm starting to study about Data Science and trying to preprocess a DataSet. I have 11 columns (col1 to col11) and to each one of that i wanna apply this:

exemple with second column witch is col2

```
col2Media = df['col2'][df['col2'] != '-'].astype(str).astype(int).values.mean() 

df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: col2Media.astype(int) if x == '-' else x)
```

It's like a **for** in **C** with **i** as column index:

```
for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) { 
    MediaCol(i) = df['col(i)'][df['col(i)'] != '-'].astype(str).astype(int).values.mean() 
    df['col(i)'] = df['col(i)'].apply(lambda x: MediaCol(i).astype(int) if x == '-' else x)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to program the same loop in python. I suppose `colMedia` serves only as a temporary Series.

```
for i in range(1,12):
    colMedia = df['col'+str(i)][df['col'+str(i)] != '-'].astype(str).astype(int).values.mean() 
    df['col'+str(i)] = df['col'+str(i)].apply(lambda x: colMedia.astype(int) if x == '-' else x)
```

Or if `col1` to `col11` are the only columns of your dataframe:

```
for col in df:
    colMedia = df[col][df[col] != '-'].astype(str).astype(int).values.mean() 
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: colMedia.astype(int) if x == '-' else x)
```